# Help identifying possible seeds

Tags: identification, seeds

Does anyone recognize these bugs/seeds? They are tiny, exactly the size and shape of a chia seed, and each one has two white spots. They are all over my rugs. [image]

Comment: Would you please find some way of magnifying them?  Are they hard?  What happens if you try to slice one in half?  I was thinking maybe a pupa (stage in some insects) maybe.  Or some animal droppings.  The two white spots have me stumped.